# How to sign out from Firebase Auth when using Google Auth, in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

What is the correct way to sign out when using Google Auth? I'm doing it like the code below, but I also tried using only the `mFirebaseAuth.signOut()` and it seems to work fine, so do I really need to call the sign out method from `GoogleSignInClient`?

```
mFirebaseAuth.signOut();
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();
    
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getBaseContext(), gso);
    mGoogleSignInClient.signOut();
```

Comment: Yes, you should sign out from both Firebase and Google, otherwise, you'll remain logged in with one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct to assume that `FirebaseAuth.signOut()` is sufficient. This is because the firebase app itself is managing its own user object that all firebase services use. Doing so, also resets the `currentUser` to null.

The only issue would be if your app attempts to sign the user in automatically from the Google Client and in some cases, signing out on that service can be desirable but they are not related to Firebase and its services.

Comment: So it is better to just leave both signout methods in the code, right?

Comment: In general, that is hard to say. but to make life easier, yes.